# How to pass URL parameters to a joomla module

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have my own nice link http://www.link.com/sometext, now I would "enhance" this having the opportunity to write something like http://www.link.com/sometext?parameters=myParam cause I need to send a parameters to the article called by sometext.

Can I do something like that??? How can I pass parameters through the URL???? How can i get it's value?

Regards

Comment: Are you trying to pass parameters to a module or a Joomla article? Those are two very different goals with different methods to achieve each.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the standard Joomla way to retrieve GET/POST requests. This link should get you started:
http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_data_from_GET_and_POST_requests

```
$address = JRequest::getVar('address');
```

**EDIT** - just saw your other comment. To use PHP inside article, try something like Sourcerer: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/5051